# less doesn't work in LXC container

Tags: terminal, lxc, expect, less

I'm experiencing some trouble running less and expect inside LXC container (whether using console or SSH)

Expect won't work before I won't add an "interact" anywhere in the script, and less doesn't show any output, and exits with status 1 :

```
[root@app-lxc log]# less messages 
[root@app-lxc log]# echo $?
1
```

I think those two problems are related, and have something to do with terminal settings.

Comment: If you think it is related to terminal settings, then the output of `echo "$TERM"` should certainly be included in your question.

Comment: Explaining _why_ you think it has something to do with terminal settings is a good idea, too.